# How to find the order of the group?

Tags: group-theory, symmetry

*Translation:* If $G$ is a finite group in which every element $g \in G$ satisfies $g^2 = e$, where $e$ is the unit element of $G$, then what are the possible values for the order $k=|G|$ of $G$?

*Original:* There is a group with $k$ elements $G = (g_{i})$, for all elements of which $g_{i}^{2} = e$, where $e$ is the unit element. How to get the order of the group (the properties of the elements of the group leads to restrictions on the number of k)?

Comment: If a group has $k$ elements then the order of the group is equal to $k$. Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: Do you mean there are $\;k\;$ elements in the group which squared are the unit (i.e., involutions), or that **all** the elements in the group are involutions?

Comment: @JohnSmith : k can't be any, probably property of elements imposes restrictions.

Comment: @DonAntonio : the first (see also my previous comment).

Comment: You should perhaps rephrase your question a bit.

Comment: I just can't understand what you wrote to John smith, @JohnTaylor..."elements of property imposes restrictions"??

Comment: You may want to ask the question in your native language as well. Someone can then improve the translation.

Comment: @DonAntonio : maybe, the property $g_{i}^2 = e$ imposes restrictions on possible values of $k$.

Comment: @JohnTaylor Is this correct: You have a group $G$ in which you have exactly $k$ number of elements $g \ G$ such that $g^2=e$ ?

Comment: It seems the question is: if $G$ is a $k$-generated group, where all the generators square to the identity, then what is $|G|$? By the way, @JohnSmith: it may be an ambiguity in language, but "a group with $k$ elements ... for which ..." does not mean that the order of the group is $k$.

Comment: @user115654 Of course :) I'm sorry for my sloppiness!

Answer (score 3):

You might note that $a^2=e$ and $b^2=e$ and $(ab)^2=abab=e$. From this last, using the associative law we get $a(abab)b=a(e)b=ab$

Then $a^2bab^2=ebae=ba=ab$

So the group is abelian of exponent 2. Do you know any structure theorem about such groups which might suggest the possible orders?

Comment: @JackSchmidt Thanks, changed.

Comment: +1 as soon as OP confirms this was his question. I think it is, but he could be asking about groups generated by involutions, or some sort of sequence group.

Comment: @JackSchmidt: Now that I think about it, asking the order of a group generated by $k$ involutions may not have a sensible answer. For example $S_n$ is generated by involutions

Comment: If all elements have order 2, this is the way to go. If the group is generated by involutions, without all elements being involutions, a different answer is required. This is how I read OP - but it is not clear.

Comment: Thank you! This is the answer on my poorly formulated question. Can you explain why there is the consequence about $2^{n}$ as about the order of the group from its abelian nature?